# vagrant up: Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

When doing a `vagrant up` I get:

```
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.0.28
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.1.18
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
```

I had a quick search but nothing that resolves this.

It doesn't seem to be impacting anything so just wondered what the best practice is here...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Possibly too late for OP but in case it helps anyone else, comments in the [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin project on GitHub suggest the additions are installed correctly but reported incorrectly. Updating to the latest version fixed it for me:

```
vagrant plugin update
Updating installed plugins...
Updated 'vagrant-vbguest' to version '0.14.2'!
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue on `Ubuntu 18.04` with `Virtualbox 5.2.18`

Fix: add the following lines to your vagrant file.

```
if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
    config.vbguest.auto_update = false  
end
```

See this comment [at github](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/333#issuecomment-485077634)

Comment: Typical follow up error: Stderr from the command:  E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64'

Answer (score 4):

I've found a working solution. Add the following code to your Vagrantfile somewhere in the *Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|* section.

```
if Vagrant.has_plugin? "vagrant-vbguest"
  config.vbguest.no_install  = true
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false
  config.vbguest.no_remote   = true
end
```

Comment: I fixed it with the other solution without `no_remote` and without `no_install`

Answer (score 0):

**IN CASE you are using vagrant, from ubuntu's apt repository**, uninstall it and step away from the scenario immediately!

`sudo apt-get purge vagrant`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

**Now download vagrant's `.deb` by Hashicop from https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html install and the error would be gone *IN CASE you installed vagrant from apt***

*`clean` and `autoremove` is important to prevent the installer from using cached files from apt even when you use the `.deb`!!*

Comment: After a full wasted day, I was able to sought out the issue. I noticed the mismatch error was alternating between the host and guest, When I decided to manually install vbguest in the guest myself to suite host, the mismatch would then switch to the host showing the initial version it complained was on the guest if I updated the host version to current guest version, it would again complain-of/change the version on the guest despite `vboxmanage` reporting the right version on the host and the guest holding the right version as well.